# Периодическая задержка отрисовки движения предметов в SDL 1.2

Tags: c++, sdl

Реализую отображение равномерно падающих яблок с верха экрана. В следующей части функции отсчитываются "такты" и в соответствии со скоростью каждого объекта выполняется отрисовка (например, 1 - перемещение каждый такт, 2 - перемещение каждые 2 такта):

```
while (true)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i]->Redraw (tact);

    tact++;
    SDL_Flip (screen);
    SDL_Delay (16);
}
```

Функция Redraw() сначала восстанавливает ту часть фона, которая должна быть видна после перемещения объекта, затем отсчитывает перемещение и отрисовывает объект в новом месте:

```
void FRUIT :: Redraw (short tact)
{
    prev_coord = coord; prev_coord.h = 1;
    SDL_BlitSurface (background, &prev_coord, screen, &coord);
    if (tact % speed == 0) coord.y++;
    SDL_BlitSurface (fruit.Picture, NULL, screen, &coord);
}
```

Движение отображается правильно, кроме одного момента: через равные (на взгляд) промежутки времени перемещение объектов приостанавливается на долю секунды. Чем это может быть вызвано и как может быть связано с используемыми функциями?

Comment: Длительность кадров измеряли? Во время рывков заметно, что длительность увеличилась? Пригодился бы [mcve] - законченная программа, которую мы могли бы запустить у себя и повторить проблему. И если не секрет, почему SDL старый? Уже есть SDL 2.0...

Comment: Это случаем не на windows запускается?

Comment: @user7860670 На Windows 7.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет, длительность кадров не измерял. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Comment: SDL_Delay там реализован через Sleep и работать будет абы как.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я сделал замеры через high_resolution_clock и получил следующие результаты: при нормальном такте на вычисления уходит 0.0010-0.0011 мс и на задержку 0.016000-0.016001 мс, как и должно быть, но в неопределённый момент время на вычисления удваивается, а после задержка увеличивается на 2 мс:`57. 0.001001 0.016000    58. 0.002001 0.016001    59. 0.001000 0.016000    60. 0.001001 0.016000    61. 0.001001 0.018001    62. 0.001000 0.016001
63. 0.001000 0.016000
64. 0.000000 0.016001
65. 0.000000 0.016001
66. 0.000000 0.016001
67. 0.000000 0.016001
68. 0.001000 0.016001`

Comment: К предыдущему комментарию: 0.001 секунд, т.е. 1 мс на вычисления

Comment: Я пытался заменить аргумент SDL_Delay с просто 16 мс на разницу (16 минус время на вычисления), но всё равно получаю торможение картинки: `64. 0.001000 0.015001   65. 0.001000 0.020001   66. 0.000000 0.017001   67. 0.001000 0.015001`